I added the pathway to minGW in environment variables, but the system doesn't see it FIXED
EDIT: Fixed the problem by simply restarting my computer, thanks everyone for answers and suggestions.
When I change the directory manually in the command prompt to the bin of mingw, and run g++ --version through the command prompt it gives me the version of the minGW. manual change But if I run the same command without changing anything in cmd, it says that g++ is not recognized as an internal or external command. I installed all the packages during installation. red is my nameg++ is not recognized as an internal or external command but in russian
I saw a similar post and I saw that I did not have all the mingw-gcc-g++ packages. After installing them nothing changed.

Please do not show pictures of text. Instead copy&paste your text (code, error message, all other text) directly into your question as formatted text.

Your PATH does not include the folder where you installed mingw. How is Windows supposed to find it then? Also, are you sure that some XY_Downloads folder is a good place to install your compiler?

Be sure to point PATH at the "bin" directory, not the MinGW directory. Also, if you're updating the PATH using system settings, you'll have to restart your command tool for the update to apply.
